# Numpy Reshape Memory error

Tags: python, numpy

I want to reshape list of images and the train_data size is 639976.
this is how I am importing images,

```
  train_data=[]
    for img in tqdm(os.listdir('Images/train/images')):
            path=os.path.join ('Images/train/images/',img)
            image=cv2.imread(path,cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
            image=cv2.resize(image, (28,28)).astype('float32')/255
            train_data.append(image)
    return train_data



  np.reshape(train_data,(-1,28,28,3))
```

I am getting memory error here.

```
 np.reshape(train_data,(-1,28,28,3))
```

Error:

> return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)
>   
> MemoryError

Comment: The size of your data is not an integer multiple of `28*28*3`. That's what causes `.reshape()` to fail.

Comment: It's a list of arrays where each image is imported as ( 28*28) as float32 type.

Comment: Be precise. A list of arrays is not an multidim-array / np.array. Furthermore, most common images are not automatically casted to float (usually: uint8). The code you show miss all those details.

Comment: Oh, so you apply `np.reshape` to a _list_ of images of presumably different sizes. NumPy attempts to convert them into a 4-dimensional array and fails because the sizes are not the same. You should either make sure that all elements of `train_data` have the same size or reshape each element independently.

Comment: I have edited my post. I have no problem in importing images(28*28). I think I have reshaped them while importing. But why I am getting error later on?

Comment: Your float-cast worsen things: you will use 4 times as much memory as needed. So the original memory is someling like 5.8GB; reshaping when lists are involved probably need the same temp-memory as numpy will allocate a new array (that's a guess; not sure what reshape does with lists). Do you know what you are doing? This float-cast is critical (at least a factor in terms of memory-usage). How much memory is available?

Comment: You mean I should not add " astype('float32')/255 " as its increasing memory. Correct me If I am wrong is not it good for faster processing ?

Comment: It is for some operations (BLAS, LAPACK). But instead of uint8 = 1 byte per channel you will use 4 bytes per channel. We don't know if you plan to input this to a neural-network or whatever, often assuming fp-types. Furthermore: answering the *how much memory question* could give some info on this problem itself.

Comment: So what do you suggest should I import all images again without adding "astype('float32')/255" ? and then try numpy reshape?

Comment: We don't know what you are doing and what your system looks like! So: no recommendation at all! To be honest: in most scenarios: do this once; output to HDF5. Then you will never do this preprocessing again for following pipeline-steps. This could also be done incrementally if you cannot hold your data at once. An alternative is numpy's memmap.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like `train_data` is a large list of small arrays. I'm not familiar with `cv2`, so I'm guessing that the

```
image=cv2.resize(image, (28,28)).astype('float32')/255
```

creates (28,28) or (28,28,3) array of floats.  By itself, not very big. Apparently that works.

The error is in:

```
np.reshape(train_data,(-1,28,28,3))
```

Since `train_data` is list, `reshape` has to first create an array, probably with `np.array(train_data)`.  If the all the components are (28,28,3) this array will already be `(n,28,28,3)` shape. But that's where the memory error occurs.  Apparently there are some of these small(ish) arrays, that it doesn't have memory to assemble them into one big array.

I'd experiment with a subset of the files.

```
In [1]: 639976*28*28*3
Out[1]: 1505223552  # floats
In [2]: _*8
Out[2]: 12041788416   # bytes
```

What's that, 12gb array?  I'm not surprise you get a memory error.  The list of arrays takes up more than that space, but they can be scattered in small blocks through out memory and swap.  Make an array from the list and you double the memory usage.

Just for fun, try to make a blank array of that size:

```
np.ones((639976,28,28,3), 'float32')
```

If that works, try to make two.

Comment: Awesome, I understand the problem. Its because I am importing a mixture of Grayscale and coloured images as coloured images. Now comm.Scatter and comm.Gatherv would work or any other code example here?

Comment: If the list has a mix of 2 and 3d arrays then `np.array` will create an object dtype array without consuming too much more memory.  But the reshape won't work, with an error message about wrong number of elements.