# h5py - reshape dataset like numpy.reshape()

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, h5py

I want to  **reshape my h5py dataset** like I can do with **numpy.reshape()**.
The following Code is only working if I use **numpy.array()** at the beginning of the code. But that only works with a small dataset and blows up my memory if I take a bigger one.

```
import h5py
import numpy as np

#load data
h5py_data_path = 'any\path\to\h5pyData\training.data.h5'
t_data = h5py.File(h5py_data_path,'r')
training_data = t_data['training.data']
######################################
#### Don't want to have this (blows up my memory) ####
training_data = np.array(training_data)
######################################

print('training_data    ',training_data.shape)
#out: training_data     (10203, 5, 341)

#reshape data
######################################
#### That works, but only with upper Numpy Code ####
training_data = training_data.reshape(training_data.shape[0], 1, 5, 341)
######################################

print('training_data    ',training_data.shape)
#out: training_data     (10203, 1, 5, 341)
```

Is there any native way in h5py to reshape that in any other working way?

Comment: What part of the `h5py` docs don't you understand?

Comment: `training_data[0:n]` loads a slice of the dataset into memory.

Comment: The HDF5 file is an ondisk data structure. As such, there isn't a native `.reshape()` method. However there is a `.resize()` method to add to an existing dataset. When you access a dataset as a numpy array, you are getting a view (in memory) of the ondisk data. In your example, you are adding a dimension to the array (from (10203, 5, 341) to (10203, 1, 5, 341)). What is your intent? If you really need to reshape your training data, you can read the dataset, reshape it and write to new dataset. The new dataset can go in the current file, or a new one.

Comment: training_data = t_data['training_data'].value.reshape(shape values) worked but still had memory issue. Seems it‘s decent to reprepare the data to its new shape...

Comment: Yeah, that's a large array to reshape. Note `.value` is deprecated in h5py. Recommended method is now like numpy array slicing: `training_data = t_data['training_data'][:]` (to access the entire array). It will accept .reshape() method.

Comment: Also, check out this SO Q&A: [numpy-reshape-memory-error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48958509) for a very similar discussion. It might be useful to your situation.

Comment: Your deleted answer suggests that loading a dataset with `np.array(dataset)` uses more memory that `dataset.value` or `dataset[:]`.  `np.array(dataset)` may be loading as `value` does, and then make a copy of it (and then delete the original load).  `np.asarray(dataset)` would have been better, but still not needed.

Answer (score 0):

While a nice to have feature, the H5py documentation is explicit: The dataset rank (number of dimensions) is fixed when it is created.