# Why am I getting Memory error getting in this code python?

Tags: python-3.x, conv-neural-network

```
X = np.array(X).reshape(-1, 80, 80, 3) 
y = np.array(y)
```

-> X = X/255.0 memory error (I am getting memory error in this line)

Comment: You should complete your question with X.shape (the -1 "hides" its real size). Then maybe you'll realize that this first dimension makes X just as big as half your computer's memory...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48958509/numpy-reshape-memory-error

Answer (score 0):

I think what you really want to do is:

```
X = np.array(X).reshape(len(X), 80, 80, 3)
```

You should provide the 1st dimension.

Comment: That should not explain the MemoryErrror